# weblogic ejb 3.1 initial-beans-in-free-pool annotation

Tags: ejb, weblogic

I am working on weblogic 12.1.3 and ejb 3.1.  I have stateless session beans and message driven beans.

There initial bean pool size is declared in weblogic-ejb-jar.xml as

```
   <ejb-name>CalculatorSession</ejb-name>
    <stateless-session-descriptor>
        <pool>
            <initial-beans-in-free-pool>20</initial-beans-in-free-pool>
        </pool>
    </stateless-session-descriptor>
    <enable-call-by-reference>true</enable-call-by-reference>
```

I dont want to have them in xml. Instead trying to configure them in StatelessSessionBean Java classes using Annotations.  What Annotations are used to substitute beans pool size and call by reference tags ? Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ejb Pooling is a topic that is not cover by the ejb 3.1 [specification](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3.1-pfd-oth-JSpec/), thus, every Java EE compliant server can implement Ejb Pooling using different strategies.

Therefore:

a) you won't find any standar annotation (provided by the specification) related to Pooling.

b) you need to find out if your server offers the needed annotation.

As this [table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24977/summary.htm) shows, Weblogic only allows to configure this property in a deployment descriptor file.